# Hibernate left join always hit the base

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have next service:

```
public void checkAll() {
    Session sess = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    System.out.println("Check 1");
    Query query = sess.createQuery("select distinct t from House t left join fetch Kw k on t.id=k.fkHouse "
            + "left join fetch Kart a on k.id=a.fkKw "
            + "left join fetch Reg r on a.lsk=r.lsk "
            + "left join fetch RegState s on a.lsk=s.lsk "
            + " "
            + "where t.klsk = 187804");
    System.out.println("Check 2");
    List<House> lst =query.list(); 
    for (House o : lst) {
        System.out.println("Check 3");
        for (Kw kw : o.getKw()) {
            for (Kart kart : kw.getLsk()) {
                for (Reg reg : kart.getReg()) {
                    System.out.print("Reg="+reg.getDtReg());    
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Check 4");
}
```

I've turned on SQL Debug of Hibernate an see next:

```
Check 1
2393 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Check 2
2547 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select distinct house0_.ID as ID1_1_, house0_.FK_K_LSK as FK_K_LSK2_1_, house0_.FK_STREET as FK_STREET3_1_ from AR.HOUSE house0_ left outer join AR.KW kw1_ on (house0_.ID=kw1_.FK_HOUSE)left outer join AR.KART kart2_ on (kw1_.ID=kart2_.FK_KW)left outer join PS.REG reg3_ on (kart2_.LSK=reg3_.LSK)left outer join PS.REG_STATE regstate4_ on (kart2_.LSK=regstate4_.LSK) where house0_.FK_K_LSK=187804
Check 3
2609 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select kw0_.FK_HOUSE as FK_HOUSE3_3_0_, kw0_.ID as ID1_3_0_, kw0_.ID as ID1_3_1_, kw0_.FK_K_LSK as FK_K_LSK2_3_1_, kw0_.FK_HOUSE as FK_HOUSE3_3_1_ from AR.KW kw0_ where kw0_.FK_HOUSE=?
2655 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select kart0_.FK_KW as FK_KW4_2_0_, kart0_.LSK as LSK1_2_0_, kart0_.LSK as LSK1_2_1_, kart0_.FK_K_LSK as FK_K_LSK2_2_1_, kart0_.FIO as FIO3_2_1_, kart0_.FK_KW as FK_KW4_2_1_ from AR.KART kart0_ where kart0_.FK_KW=?
2657 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select reg0_.LSK as LSK6_15_0_, reg0_.ID as ID1_15_0_, reg0_.ID as ID1_15_1_, reg0_.DT_REG as DT_REG2_15_1_, reg0_.DT_REG_TS as DT_REG_TS3_15_1_, reg0_.DT_UNREG as DT_UNREG4_15_1_, reg0_.DT_UNREG_TS as DT_UNREG_TS5_15_1_, reg0_.LSK as LSK6_15_1_, reg0_.FK_PERS as FK_PERS7_15_1_, reg0_.FK_REG_STATUS as FK_REG_STATUS8_15_1_, reg0_.FK_REG_TP as FK_REG_TP9_15_1_ from PS.REG reg0_ where reg0_.LSK=?
Reg=1996-03-12 00:00:00.0Check 4
3382 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select distinct house0_.ID as ID1_1_, house0_.FK_K_LSK as FK_K_LSK2_1_, house0_.FK_STREET as FK_STREET3_1_ from AR.HOUSE house0_ left outer join AR.KW kw1_ on (house0_.ID=kw1_.FK_HOUSE)left outer join AR.KART kart2_ on (kw1_.ID=kart2_.FK_KW)left outer join PS.REG reg3_ on (kart2_.LSK=reg3_.LSK)left outer join PS.REG_STATE regstate4_ on (kart2_.LSK=regstate4_.LSK) where house0_.FK_K_LSK=187804
```

At point "Check 1" I see SQL with joins and it is good,
but why at point "Check 3" I see weird SQLs, which hit the base again?

I forced hibernate to load all childs using "left join fetch" at point "Check 1", 
but why it need again to retreive childs from the database?

Please help me, may be I need to change approach with getting child entities?
May be it is Hibernate N+1 problem I have to solve?

Comment: I tried to add @BatchSize(size = 50) to my @OneToMany joins... it seriously increase speed of fetching, but now i see another weird SQL, but not see left joins :select kart0_.FK_KW as FK_KW4_2_1_, kart0_.LSK as LSK1_2_1_, kart0_.LSK as LSK1_2_0_, kart0_.FK_K_LSK as FK_K_LSK2_2_0_, kart0_.FIO as FIO3_2_0_, kart0_.FK_KW as FK_KW4_2_0_ from AR.KART kart0_ where kart0_.FK_KW in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: And moreover I've checked my entities joins and found mistake. Thanks to the @shankarsh15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are experiencing a `"N+1" select` problem.

To avoid `N+1 select` problem, just make sure that you join fetch all associations involved with House Entity especially One-One association.

Also HQL should be written in a manner like in example show below ,

```
 SELECT employee FROM Employee employee  LEFT JOIN FETCH employee.employer
```

Please go through the HQL docs below:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from

Comment: And moreover I've checked my entities joins and found mistake. Thanks to the @shankarsh15